# PHP see if a 'last sent' date was 30+ days ago

Tags: php

I have this PHP Code:

```
$last_sent=strtotime('2013-08-12');
if($last_sent < strtotime('now +30 days'))
{
    echo 'send survey';
}
else
{
    echo 'dont send survey';
}
```

i need to see if the `$last_sent` date is 30 days ago or more than 30 days ago. this doesnt seem to be working though.

i i change the last sent date to 2013-07-12 (exactly 30 days ago) it echoes `send survey` and then when i change the date to today (2013-08-12) it still says 'send survey'

Comment: You are currently checking to see if it was sent before 30 days from now.... I think you need to put the +30 on the other side of your comparison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `strtotime('now +30 days')` use `strtotime('-30 days')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$last_sent < time() - 30 * 24 * 3600
```

Comment: This solution is probably faster - it doesn't have to parse and interpret the relative time, it just has to do the arithmetic.  Both posted solutions should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with dateTime object, this kind of objects can be compared :

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2013-08-12');
$date2 = new DateTime('+30 days);
if($date2 > $date1) //do somethings
```

another solution is date_diff : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php